# CSV React-Native Expo

Tags: react-native, csv, expo

Problema simples, quero carregar um arquivo .csv e rodar um console.log(arquivo) no react-native Expo,
mas quando eu tento encontrar o arquivo no meu diretório, o react-native simplesmente trata como se o arquivo não existisse. Se eu mudar o arquivo para .json sem mexer em mais nada, ele encontra e funciona, porem, enquanto é .csv, simplesmente trata como se não existisse.

Simple problem, I want to load a .csv file and run a console.log(file) in react-native Expo,
but when I try to find the file in my directory, react-native simply treats it as if the file doesn't exist. If I change the file to .json without changing anything else, it finds it and works, however, while it is .csv, it simply treats it as if it didn't exist.

.................................